# Why the notation small $l$ is used in $l^p$ space?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have heard that the capital ell-pee $L^p$ space was first used or invented by Lebesgue. Thus the notation $L$ is used. (I may be wrong!) I was wondering why the small $l$ notation is used in denoting $l^p$ space. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: $\ell^p$ is just $L^p$ with the counting measure. perhaps someone just decided to standardize once and for all to use small letter $l$ to denote spaces with counting measure…

Comment: Okay. So, small $\ell$ or capital $L$ notations are to honor Lebesgue, right?

Comment: That’s the story I’ve been told, the story I tell myself and others, but I can’t confirm if it’s actually historically accurate.

Comment: Aren't $L^p$ spaces actually called "Lebesgue spaces" anyway?

Comment: Similarly $c$  usually denotes the space of convergent sequences or equivalently continuous functions on one-point compactification of positive integers, while capital $C$ is usually used for continuous functions on $[a,b]$  or continuous and bounded functions on more general topological spaces. It seems there is no particular name behind "C" (perhaps Cantor ?).